# append matrix to stl matrix (2d std::vector)

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, c++14

Is this the way to append rows (matrix) to a matrix?

```
#include <vector>
#include <memory>
using std::vector;

int size = 4; // width;
int chunk = 2; // high
int main(int argc, char const *argv[]) {
    vector<vector<int>> m(10, vector<int>(size));

    auto func = []() {
        vector<vector<int>> n(chunk, vector<int>(size));
        return n;
    };
    int j = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        auto n = func();
        for(auto &row : n) m[j++] = row; // append rows
    }
}
```

I hoped it will be possible to just `m.push_back(n)`.

Comment: yes, but row-by-row: `m.push_back(n[0]); m.push_back(n[1]); ...`

Comment: Always row-by-row? No single shot?

Comment: The comment says "append row", but the code in fact replaces the existing row with the new one. The whole loop is a very elaborate no-op  - `m` ends up in the exact same state after it as it was before. What again are you trying to achieve?

Comment: What you shown is, simply copying everything from `n` to `m`. If that's your intention, why don't you simply: `m = std::move(func());` ? then an extra allocation for `m` also avoided.

Comment: Well, I have to do it 5 times, each time loading (transfering/moving) 2 rows in m.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you're looking for is:

```
m.insert(m.end(), n.begin(), n.end());
```

This will however copy the contents of `n`. If you don't need `n` anymore after that it would be more efficient to move the rows using `move_iterator` adapter:

```
m.insert(m.end(),
    std::make_move_iterator(n.begin()),
    std::make_move_iterator(n.end()));
```